# gwt maven plugin - Is mojo.codehaus.org down?

Tags: gwt-maven-plugin

what happened to http://mojo.codehaus.org ?

Trying to enter in url http://www.codehaus.org.

```
This domain has expired. If you are the owner of this domain, please click here to renew it.
```

is it serious ?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it.  As far as I can tell the codehaus.org domain is down completely.  This means any subdomain goes with it (mojo., groovy., etc.).  According to twitter they know about it (Secondhand, may not be reputable): https://twitter.com/QwestUA/status/439094407670005760.  Nothing to do but wait till it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Codehaus is [dead](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2892227/open-source-tools/codehaus-the-once-great-house-of-code-has-fallen.html).
You can find some old codehaus contents at:
https://www.mojohaus.org/
https://github.com/codehaus